# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am getting this error when trying to submit form, or when trying to log in and also when I click on registration I get HTTP ERROR 500. Funny thing is that when I test same application locally over XAMPP there is no issues but looks like my webservers does have issues with it.

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:
in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 655
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 629
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 607
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 268
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 150
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Website can be viewed at:

> [Webuilder](https://www.webuilder.co.uk)

So the question here is: Why do I get this error on my webserver but over xampp, locally everything is fine

/Edit://

Adding code:

Form:

```
@extends('layouts.master') @section('title', 'Website Builder') @section('content')
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
<div class=flex-container>
    <div class="flex-item templates">

        @foreach ($templates as $template)
        <a class="content-link" href="{{ asset($template->file )}}">
        <img class="template_img" src="{{ asset($template->image )}}"/>
        </a> @endforeach

    </div>

    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left hiding_template left_side arrows"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right hiding_features right_side arrows"></span>
    <div class="pace pace-inactive">
        <div class="pace-progress" data-progress-text="100%" data-progress="99" style="width: 100%;">
            <div class="pace-progress-inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pace-activity"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="content-link2" class="flex-item2">
    @if (session('status'))
    <div id="mydiv" class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
    @endif
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item  featuress">
        <input class="form-control filestyle margin images" data-input="false" type="file" data-buttonText="Upload Logo" data-size="sm" data-badge="false" onchange="readURL(this);" />

        <script>
            $(function() {
                $(document).tooltip();
            });
        </script>
        <button style="display: none" class="form-control margin btn btn-primary hide_all" id="showColor">Show Colors</button>
        <button style="display: none" class="form-control margin btn btn-primary hide_all" id="hideColor">Hide Colors</button>
        <input title="Choose a color and then click on any box" style="display: none" class="btn btn-default form-control margin hide_all" type="color" id="colorChoice">
        <a style="display: none" href="#" class="btn btn-default form-control margin hide_all" id="cp4">Background</a>

        <button style="display: none" onclick="$('#fonts1').bfhfonts({font: 'Arial'})" id="fontsShow" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin hide_all">Load Fonts</button>
        <button style="display: none" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin hide_all" id="fontsHide">Hide Fonts</button>
        <select title="Choose a font and then click on any box" style="display: none" id="fonts1" class="form-control margin hide_all"></select>

        <button style="display: none" onclick="$('#googlefonts1').bfhgooglefonts({font: 'Lato'})" id="googleShow" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin hide_all">Google fonts</button>
        <button style="display: none" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin hide_all" id="googleHide">Hide Google</button>
        <select title="Choose a font and then click on any box" style="display: none" id="googlefonts1" class="form-control margin hide_all"></select>

        <button style="display: none" onclick="$('#fontsizes1').bfhfontsizes({fontsize: '12'})" id="sizeShow" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin hide_all">Load font size</button>
        <button style="display: none" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin hide_all" id="sizeHide">Hide font size</button>
        <select title="Choose a font size and then click on any box" style="display: none" id="fontsizes1" class="form-control margin hide_all"></select>

        <button style="display: none" class="form-control margin btn btn-warning hide_all" id="finishEdit">Done</button>
        <button class="form-control margin btn btn-default" id="startEdit">Edit</button>


        <button class="btn btn-success form-control margin " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalHorizontal">
    Save Website
</button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModalHorizontal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <!-- Modal Header -->
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                       <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                            Website Name
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form action="{{ action('BuilderController@postDB') }}" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                                <input type="hidden" id="code" name="newCode" value="">
                                <input type="hidden" id="name" name="newName" value="">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="website_name">Name</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="website_name" placeholder="Website Name" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal Footer -->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="form-control margin btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">
                            Close
                </button>
                        <button onClick=" updateDatabase(this);" type="submit" class="form-control margin btn btn-success" id="getRequest changes">
                    Save Website
                </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>

        </div>
        </body>
        <link href="{{asset('css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="{{asset('css/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="{{asset ('//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js') !!}">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/bootstrap-formhelpers.js') !!}">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/template.js') !!}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js') !!}">
        </script>

        </html>
        @endsection @show
```

Login:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
<div class="container forms">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Login</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Login
                                </button>

                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">
                                    Forgot Your Password?
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Register: (Here I get error 500)

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
<div class="container forms">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Register</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/register') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Register
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::get('home', 'BuilderController@homepage');
    Route::get('pages', 'BuilderController@websites');
    Route::get('template', 'BuilderController@templates');
    Route::post('template', 'BuilderController@postDB');
    Route::get('logout', 'BuilderController@getLogout');
    Route::get('/website/{name}', 'BuilderController@website');
}); 
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('layouts/home');
});
Auth::routes();

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Voyager::routes();
});
```

Comment: Your link is broken, but even if it weren't you should be posting code and not just a link.

Comment: https://www.webuilder.co.uk/ link is working fine

Comment: and I am not exactly sure what code you need because same code works fine locally just not on server

Comment: The form + the login method you're using.

Comment: 1) Make sure that you are including the csrf token on your form (i.e `csrf_token()`) 2) Make sure that you cookies and/or session information is being retained between page loads as this can be symptom of loss of session

Comment: added code, please have a look at it

Comment: Did you given the permission to log folder. `chmod 777 -R storage/logs` ?

Comment: Pretty sure I did but I will double check

Comment: well looks like that solved the issue but I am sure I did that before, write it as an answer so I can accept @Vikash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have given the write permission.
Go to your root folder and write those two commands.

```
chmod 777 -R storage/logs
chmod 777 -R bootstrap/cache
```

Without these command Laravel won't be able to do caching and print the error in logs (if needed). Laravel will need those file permission.